# Sorting two related lists

Tags: python, python-2.x

I have code that sorts two lists related with each other

```
"""
    list1 reperesents customer
    list2 reperesents amount of products they have brought
"""

list1=['a','c','e','i','o','u']
list2=[12,23,45,10,7,2]
list3=[]
for i in range(0,len(list1)):
        list3.append([list1[i],list2[i]])
print list3
"""
    [['a', 12], ['c', 23], ['e', 45], ['i', 10], ['o', 7], ['u', 2]]
"""
list3=sorted(list3,key=lambda x: list3[list3.index(x)][1])

print(list3)
"""
    [['u', 2], ['o', 7], ['i', 10], ['a', 12], ['c', 23], ['e', 45]]
"""
for i in range(0.len(list3)):
    list1[i]=list3[i][0]
    list2[i]=list3[i][1]

print list1
print list2
```

List1 is the customers' names
List2 is the number of products each customer bought

So:

- 'a' bought 12 products
- 'c' bought 23 products

And so on.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You should ask review on actual code, not on anonymised code. (There's lots of room for improvement though)

Comment: posted code has an error (your second use of range() has 0.len instead of 0, len)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should probably just change how the data is stored. You should have one list which contains all of a customers data. For instance, a dictionary that follows this template:

```
{"name": "a", "purchased": 12}
```

If you had a list of those, it would be trivial to sort them, using the list sorting functions.

```
customer_data = [
                    {"name": "a", "purchased": 12},
                    {"name": "c", "purchased": 23},
                    {"name": "o", "purchased": 7},
                ]
customer_data.sort(key=lambda customer: customer["purchased"])
print customer_data
# [{'name': '0', 'purchased': 7}, {'name': 'a', 'purchased': 12}, {'name': 'c', 'purchased': 23}]
```

Answer (score 6):

Even though @SuperBiasedMan's answer makes a lot of sense and is the real solution, here's some things you can fix in your current approach.

First of all, do not use the `""" ... """` syntax as comments. They're multiline strings. Instead, prefix each line using `#`. (Except when you mean it as a docstring, in which case you may use `""" ... """` syntax).

```
"""
    list1 reperesents customer
    list2 reperesents amount of products they have brought
"""

list1=['a','c','e','i','o','u']
list2=[12,23,45,10,7,2]
```

First of all, the variable names do not make a lot of sense. `list1` is `customers`, while `list2` is a list of `quantities`. Better name them as such.

```
list3=[]
for i in range(0,len(list1)):
        list3.append([list1[i],list2[i]])
```

Here you're doing a loop at the Python level. Faster and cleaner would be the following:

```
list3 = zip(list1, list2)
```

The difference will be that this gives a list of tuples instead of a list of lists. That's hardly going to be a problem in the following.

```
list3=sorted(list3,key=lambda x: list3[list3.index(x)][1])
```

Let's think out loud what the lambda does: first, we find out the position of `x` in `list3`. Then, we use that position to look up the value at the given position in `list3`, (which should, in all reality, just be `x` again), and then get the second component.

Better would be to write

```
list3 = sorted(list3, key=lambda x: x[1])
```

Or, even (which we can do because there are no other references to `list3`):

```
list3.sort(key=lambda x)
```

That's so much shorter!

```
for i in range(0.len(list3)):
    list1[i]=list3[i][0]
    list2[i]=list3[i][1]
```

Fixing the typo (`.` should be `,`) is obvious.

```
for i in range(0, len(list3)):
    list1[i]=list3[i][0]
    list2[i]=list3[i][1]
```

Then, let's see if we can write this a bit differently. Yes we can!

```
list1, list2 = zip(*list3)
```

At this point, `list1` and `list2` are tuples. But that we can solve by writing

```
list1, list2 = map(list, zip(*list3))
```

instead.